# How can I get userLoginId from session using Servlets

Tags: java

I wanted to populate userLoginId in an entity, using offbiz framework when I am trying to fetch userLoginId it is fetching as system instead it has to fetch userLoginId of the person who logged in.

Comment: Can you post your code too. Because without code no one will help you.

Comment: public static Map<String, ? extends Object> updateUserLoginDetailsInInventoryItem(DispatchContext dctx, Map context) {
         Delegator delegator = dctx.getDelegator();
         LocalDispatcher dispatcher = dctx.getDispatcher();
         Map<String, ? extends Object> result = ServiceUtil.returnSuccess();
         GenericValue userLogin = (GenericValue) context.get("userLogin");

Comment: I have got log as below for userLogin.
[GenericEntity:UserLogin][createdStamp,2017-01-27 16:31:43.237(java.sql.Timestamp)][createdTxStamp,2017-01-27 16:31:43.111(java.sql.Timestamp)][currentPassword,null()][disabledDateTime,null()][enabled,N(java.lang.String)][externalAuthId,null()][hasLoggedOut,null()][isSystem,Y(java.lang.String)][lastUpdatedStamp,2018-07-21 16:39:42.922(java.sql.Timestamp)][lastUpdatedTxStamp,2018-07-21 16:39:42.912(java.sql.Timestamp)][orgId,(java.lang.String)][partyId,system(java.lang.String)][requirePasswordChange,null()][userLoginId,system(java.lang.String)]